# How can I improve this question about US Politics?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I got a warm welcome with [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34607/in-the-letter-to-cramer-how-is-being-a-north-dakotan-a-badge-of-honour) , but after incorporating the initial comments, it seems to be attracting downvotes without any clue on possible improvements.

How can I improve it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I edited your question to add some additional context. I suspect one problem was that there wasn't enough information about the context of this letter for most readers to understand what you were asking about. It wasn't clear who "Cramer" was, or what this letter was about, or why it's a political subject.

Second, we tend to close "mind reading" questions. These are questions that would require insight into the mind of a particular person to answer. For example, "What are the REAL motivations behind X" is a classic mind-reading question. No one can know the supposed "real" motivation - only the purported ones. In this case, I'm not sure how anyone could know what the author of this letter means except the author themselves.

Finally - and least importantly - the tags were somewhat confusing. This was originally tagged as a political theory question, which indicates the question expects an answer based in scientific theory or philosophy. I went ahead and removed that tag.

Comment: +1, Thanks for this. Now the question looks complete. I do not think it is only a mind reading question ; I have given other examples in the Initial Posting, like a Spartan telling his enemy "We are Spartans!" would imply "We are known for our toughness and we do not retreat!" ; there may be more examples. I used the Political theory tag, probably incorrectly or cynically, because of a "theory" that Politicians may not make sense, but only have to say emotional things to garner votes.

Comment: @Prem That's not what [political theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_philosophy) means.

Comment: @rus9384 , agreed , I was being cynical and using it incorrectly .